# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on line var new_arr = filtered.split(',');

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i wrote little bit of javascript and i'm getting error, usually it never happens but still i've no idea what i'm doing wrong here is my code 
`

```
var stu = ['ron','john','johnny','roni','rob','bob'];
        $('#studentName').keyup(function(){
            var student = $('#studentName').val();
            alert(findStu(student));
        });
        function findStu(val){
            var filtered = stu.filter(function(str){
                return str.indexOf(val) != -1;
            });
            var new_arr = filtered.split(',');
            var html = "";
            new_arr.foreach(function(element,index,array){
                console.log('a['+index+']='+element);
            });
        }
```

`

what i'm trying to do is when someone types `r` my code should return 'ron,roni,rob' sort of auto suggestions, but i'm getting error on line `var new_arr = filtered.split(',') \\ undefined is not a function`

Comment: var `filtered` is an array, not a string. You can only use `split` on strings.. [See Mozilla documentation for `filter` function](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/core-javascript-reference/the-array-object/array-filter)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to a string result of recommendations as in 'ron,roni,rob', Check the following code:

```
var stu = ['ron','john','johnny','roni','rob','bob'];
    $('#studentName').keyup(function(){
        var student = $('#studentName').val();
        alert(findStu(student));
    });
    function findStu(val){
        //Filters list of students and then create a string of its elements
        var filtered = stu.filter(function(str){
            return str.indexOf(val) != -1;
        }).join();
        var html = "";
        new_arr.foreach(function(element,index,array){
            console.log('a['+index+']='+element);
        });
    }
```

**Explanation:**

`.filter()` function will return an array of filtered elements based on your criteria. [Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

`.join()` will then join the piece of the array. [Documentation here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

Comment: Glad to help. You might wanna check when the `filtered` array is empty as well, and tell the user that 'no suggestions have been found' :)